# listview get distrubed after search. (Data show at bottom)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

[image: data get from the local database after searching. i am getting this view.]

[image]

data get from the local database after searching. i am getting this view.

```
try{                
            DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
            retailers=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();             
            String str=str_search[0];
            retailers=db.getRetailers(str);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }          

        // Keys used in Hashmap 
        String[] from = {"id","shop_name","address"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = {R.id.id,R.id.shopname,R.id.address};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item         

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(RetailersListActivity.this,retailers, R.layout.retailer_list_item, from, to);  

        return adapter;
```

is this problem related to listview or some coading problem

plz help!!!

Comment: Refresh your listview using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: If you have **transcriptMode** on your ListView it may cause this. Look at the usage of [android:transcriptMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode)

Comment: post your xml file containing `ListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your `xml` file you are setting `ListView` above the bottom Layout so try to set you xml layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    //here your search layout should be android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

     <ListView
            android:id="@+id/attendanceList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/your_search_layout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/your_bottom_layout" >
     </ListView>

    //here your bottom layout should be android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this scenario whould help you...